# Install Oracle 11g and Sql Developer on Ubuntu or windows 7

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, virtualbox, oracle-sqldeveloper

At first, sorry if my question too simple or incorrect.

So I would like to install oracle database 11 g and SQL developer. At first I tried install it on windows 7 but I was not able to finish it successfully(I know that I did something wrong , but cannot(do not want spend time) fix problem).
Then I think  that it will be much more convenient for me  if I can find some VM(say VirtualBox) image in which Oracle db 11g and SQL developer already installed(it can be even be Ubuntu image, since OS is not important for me at this point).

So my question might be strange but, do you know any site from which I will be able to download that kind of VM image?

Also in general since Development setup sometimes might be very time consuming , I think that it is possible that there are some kind of VM images for different kind of software installed(say for example JDK, git, maven , some IDE and so on ...). 
Do you  know some site in which there are that  kind of VM images?
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle provides a number of [pre-built virtual machines](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html).  The [Database App Development VM](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html#dbapp) would seem to be the most appropriate VM for you.  That's using Oracle 12.1 not Oracle 11.2 but I'm not sure if that's really a problem for you or not.